# language variable is empty for custom module

Tags: 8

The `language`variable is added to the twig variables by default but it is empty for my custom module which is rendering a page.

I tried adding `theme_preprocess_page` hook inside the `*.module` file but the variable is already set there...

Do I have to add it manually through the `routes` file or is there any alternative?

Comment: Any page template includes the language variable and this is retrieved from the language manager independently from your module. So probably you are rendering a template other than page. Can you provide more details?

Comment: I'm rendering a custom template by defining it inside the module file and referencing it from controller like `return ['#theme' => 'my_page', ...]`. So this is not a `page` in Drupal terms?

Comment: No, this is simply a custom template. You can name it like you want, but including "page" in the name doesn't make it a page template. The preprocess hook would be in your case `module/theme_preprocess_my_page` where you can add the language variable like core does this for the page template.

Comment: ... though in your case you can directly provide the language variable from the controller, a preprocess hook is only necessary if you want to change the output of other modules.

Comment: I get it now, that explains the other issues I'm having thanks... Do you know any way to tell Drupal to render it as a "page"? The "page"s can be modified in themes and I'd want the custom template I'm rendering to match the customizations in the theme...

Comment: You can customize the custom template in a theme by copying it from the module to the theme template folder.